# Convert a JSON API result to a class

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have here such a code (a request to the API)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dummy = new HttpRequest();
    try
    {
        var response = dummy.Get(
            "https://api.vk.com/method/method_name?parameters&access_token").ToString();

        richTextBox1.Text = response;
    }
    catch
    {
        richTextBox2.Text = "Error!";
    }
}
```

In response comes about such a json:

```
{"response":{"count":1318,"items":[{"id":7605931,"first_name":"Catarina","last_name":"Fox"},{"id":88593908,"first_name":"Анжелика","last_name":"Мартиросян"},{"id":10902759,"first_name":"Aneli","last_name":"Noita"},{"id":125376088,"first_name":"Саша","last_name":"Райнес"},{"id":112363011,"first_name":"Анастасия","last_name":"Махмудова"}]}}
```

Converter has issued the following classes:

```
public class Item
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public int count { get; set; }
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Response response { get; set; }
}
```

How do I correctly apply the available data to convert json to an array?

Comment: Hey there! If you're more comfortable with Russian that's OK too - ask here: [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via JSON.net library (install via Nuget)

```
RootObject bsObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response);
```

Or you can do this via JavaScriptSerializer

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

JavaScriptSerializer oJS = new JavaScriptSerializer();
RootObject oRootObject = new RootObject();
oRootObject = oJS.Deserialize<RootObject>(response);
```